# is there any scratch code for e-commerce rating system(codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing a e-commerce application like flipkart. I want the code for product rating system. I am using codeigniter framework. Does anyone know about that?

Comment: I can't understand, what do you want to know? Be clear, please!

Comment: I want the code for product rating system. Like the user can rate the products and they post the reviews there.

Comment: I will write some of tuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some simple tutorials:

[Star rating with jQuery and Codeigniter](http://sumonbd.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/star-rating-using-jquery-and-codeigniter/)

[Implement a star rating with a CodeIgniter](http://blog.markmirandilla.com/2011/09/10/implement-a-star-rating-widget-with-codeigniter/)

For more you need to create something more complex and more better.